# How to load content from URL using jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Below code work for if I used the same web URL

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("button").click(function(){
   $("#div1").load("https://www.samewebsiteurl h1");
 });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>

<button>Get External Content</button>

</body>
</html>
```

I also want to fetch my website content on the same website, but it's not working in BlogSpot because of my website on Blogger.
Here is an example of one of my blog

> http://ethiopian-adv.blogspot.com/2021/02/chemicals-and-conditioners-for-your.html

Please help me to fetch its post heading.

Comment: There is no [Access-Control-Allow-Origin](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Allow-Origin) header set in the response so they do not allow cross-domain ajax requests. Use PHP to act as a proxy using either `curl` or `file_get_contents` etc

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius this is same origin because this blogspot url is my blog and i want to fetch this blogspot h1 tag in this one post....

Comment: What you can do is use ajax to fetch the data with cors enabled in headers and then load in div